# How to specify a range for begin() and end() iterators to find first value of sub vector in a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

Hi I'm new to working with vectors and other parts of STL and I would like some help please, I have a vector of string vectors, containing a topic at the index of each sub-vector
e.g arr[1][0] = "topic1", with arr[1][1..n] containing messages related to "topic1",

To find the value of the topicID, the index of the subvector containing the topic, I'm using find() with begin() and end() iterators and effectively checking all value until a match is made, this is very inefficient as I know the topic will always be at arr[i][0], with complexity getting worse with n messages in the topic.

My current approach is shown below,
How can I refactor this to check only the element at arr[i][0] for the length of arr?

```
int getTopicID(vector< vector<string> >& arr, string topic)
{
    int topicID = 0;
    for (size_t m = 1; m < arr.size(); ++m)
    {
        auto i = find(arr[m].begin(), arr[m].end(), topic); 
        if (arr[m].end() != i) { topicID = m; break; }
        else { topicID = 0;}
    }
    return topicID;
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `if ( arr[m][0] == topic )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I refactor this to check only the element at arr[i][0] for the length of arr?

Simply don't loop over all of the elements (`std::find` being the unnecessary inner loop). Replace body of the outer loop with:

```
if (arr[m][0] == topic) {
    return m;
}
```

and after the loop:

```
return 0;
```

---

P.S. You can replace the outer loop with `std::find_if`.

Comment: Oh dear I really overcomplicated this in my head, Thanks for the answer :)